# Difference between ifconfig and ipconfig?

Tags: command-line

What is the difference between ifconfig and ipconfig? What do dhcpcd and ifconfig actually do?

Comment: `ifconfig` is a Linux/Unix command, `ipconfig` is for Windoze.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**[ipconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipconfig)** (**i**nternet **p**rotocol **config**uration) in **Microsoft Windows** is a console application that displays all current TCP/IP network configuration values and can modify Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol DHCP and Domain Name System DNS settings.

**[ifconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig)** (short for **i**nter**f**ace **config**uration) is a system administration utility in **Unix-like** operating systems to configure, control, and query TCP/IP network interface parameters from a command line interface (CLI) or in system configuration scripts.

**[dhcpcd](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Dhcpcd)** is a DHCP client. It is used to obtain an IP address and other information from a dhcp server, renew the IP address lease time, and automatically configure the network interface. The program performs a similar function as dhclient.

Comment: **dhcpd** is a server side implementation of the DHCP protocol (the ending **d** usually means "daemon" which is the Unix equivalent of Windows services).

Comment: **ipconfig** is also the name for an linux dhcp client/tool to configure network device with klibc. This is mostly used in early user space, e.g. initramfs

Comment: ipconfig is used in initramfs by Ubuntu et al, not by Fedora et al.

Comment: Really, thanks for the answer. It will kill my insomnia after years! :D

Answer (score 0):

The `ifconfig` command is used to get the information of active network-interfaces in a UNIX-like operating system such as Linux, whereas `ipconfig` is used in the Windows OS.

Comment: It seems your post add nothing to what is already included Eugene's answer, does it?